# Como fixar menu com efeito fadeIn?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Tenho o seguinte código que fixa o menu usando bootstrap:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if(scroll > 500) {
    $('.navbar').addClass('sticky-top')
  }
  else {
  $('.navbar').removeClass('sticky-top')
  }
  
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Gostaria de usar `animate` para poder fixar com algum efeito de fadein ao invés dele surgir de uma vez na tela mas não estou conseguindo.

Algúem me da uma luz de como fixar o menu com efeito?

Comment: Cara seu script está meio bugado ou é impressão minha? Parece que ele só aparece uma vez, depois não adiante vc rodar a tela novamente que o efeito não se repete... é isso mesmo que vc quer?

Comment: @hugocsl coloquei esse script só como exemplo, o foco é fazer um efeito de "esmaecimento" para exibir e ocultar o menu.

Comment: @hugocsl arrumei para ficar mais fácil de entender e ajudar. Agradeço desde já

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só verificar se a `nav` possui a classe `.sticky-top` e aplicar o `fadeIn()`. Mas antes é preciso esconder com `.hide()`:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   var nav = $('.navbar');
   if(scroll > 500) {
      if(!nav.hasClass('sticky-top')){
         nav.addClass('sticky-top')
         .hide()
         .fadeIn();
      }
   }else{
      nav.removeClass('sticky-top')
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: show! Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Fiz uma opção usando duas classes, uma para retirar o menu, outra para colocar ele de volta no lugar. Porém eu não uso `positon` ou `display` para fazer ele sumir e voltar ele sempre está fixo, mas eu movo ele para fora da tela. Preferi usar `opacity` e `top`. Pois dando `display:block/none` vc não consegue uma transição suave entende.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja como ficou no exemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>

  .navbar {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: top 1s, opacity 1s;
  }
  .mostra {
    top: 0px !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
  .esconde {
    top: -100px;
    opacity: 0;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
  
  


  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown link
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <div style="height: 350vh;"></div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 500 ){
        $('.navbar').addClass('mostra');
      } else {
        $('.navbar').removeClass('mostra');
      };    
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1 ){
        $('.navbar').addClass('esconde');
      } else {
        $('.navbar').removeClass('esconde');
      };
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Quando redimensiona a tela enche de bug. :/

Comment: @sam uai jovem eu fiz uns testes aqui em todos os breacking-points e funcionou normal, até coloquei um conteúdo alguns conteúdos na página para testar e não notei nenhum bug aparente, nem erro no console... O que apresentou ai e em qual browser?

Comment: Tô usando o Chrome mesmo. Executa o snippet e coloque em modo de tela cheia e teste. Veja que os efeitos não funcionam como no modo normal.

Comment: @sam no Snippet aqui realmente parece que não ele da algum problema quando vc muda para "tela cheia" acredito que é pq ele muda o CSS do iframe em que o código está dentro ai por algum motivo deixa de funcionar. Mas vc pode testar ai em uma janela norma e colocar em qualquer resolução que funciona 100% ;)